# Update EC2 Security Group via Python with Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a need that doesnt seem to be supported by Boto3 and I am hoping to find a solution. I need to add an ingress rule that permits both IPs and a source group as the source of the traffic.

Here is the script I am using to add IPs from a CSV file which is working great. I need to add one more rule to allow sg-blah as a source address as well.

```
import boto3
import csv

security_group_id = "sg-blah"
port_range_start = 0
port_range_end = 0
protocol = "-1"
csv_file = "/Users/user/ips.csv"
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
security_group = ec2.SecurityGroup(security_group_id)

f = open(csv_file)
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

#The next line removes all permissions
security_group.revoke_ingress(IpPermissions=security_group.ip_permissions)

for row in csv_f:
    cidr = row[0] + "/32"
#    description = row[1]
    security_group.authorize_ingress(
        DryRun=False,
        IpPermissions=[
            {
                'FromPort': port_range_start,
                'ToPort': port_range_end,
                'IpProtocol': protocol,
                'IpRanges': [
                    {
                        #                        'Description': description
                    },
                ],
                'UserIdGroupPairs': [
                    {
              #          'GroupId': security_group_id,
                    },
                ],
            }
        ]
)
```

I am getting an error saying `An error occurred (InvalidPermission.Duplicate) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: the specified rule "peer: sg-blah, ALL, ALLOW" already exists`

but it doesnt.

Comment: `IpPermissions` is a list. Simply provide multiple entries in the list.

Comment: @jarmod when I do that by adding

    UserIdGroupPairs': [
                    {
#                        'IpProtocol': protocol,                        'GroupId': security_group_id,
                        },

I get this error saying it already exists. Its like its trying to add it twice for some reason.

raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidPermission.Duplicate) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: the specified rule "peer: sg-blah, ALL, ALLOW" already exists

EDIT:Sorry I cant format

Comment: What I think is happening is that one IP is read at a time, and after each IP it tries adding sg-blah. How can I have it read the entire CSV list first before adding sg-blah?